# Does staying level 1 reduce the requirements for gaining xp/levels?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I read somewhere that staying level 1, and refusing to enter the level up screen, would allow you to get every perk.

I think the logic was something like... the game doesn't increase required experience for gaining skill levels until you take the level-up.

At first this seemed true, every sneak attack I landed raised me one full level in sneak, getting 100 right away. But grinding alchemy from 99-100 clearly doesn't have the same requirements as going from 01-02. So the game still seems to be keeping track of my levels.

If that's the case, can you really get every perk? Is there any advantage in refusing to level up, aside from easier enemies?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is completely false.

The [amount of experience](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveling) required to gain a point of skill level is:

> k(x<sup>1.95</sup> )+C

- k & C = are constants depending on the skill
- x is the current skill level

The values for sneak are:

k = 2/45
  c = 32/3

Here are the experience required for the first 10 levels of sneak:

1   10.71111111
2   10.83838868
3   11.045287
4   11.33015679
5   11.69186759
6   12.12955919
7   12.642538
8   13.23022354
9   13.89211712
10  14.62778195

You'll notice that there is not much difference in the experience required early on as this is not a linear curve.  To go from level 49-50 will require nearly 100 experience.  This may lead to the false impression that staying at lower levels means your skills go up faster, but whats really happening is if your skill level is low, its easier to improve it.

As for whether or not you can gain every perk, the amount of experience required per level is:

> Current level * 25 + 75

You gain the amount of experience points equal to the level of the skill you just obtained.  The game will 'bank' any extra experience towards the next level, but the maximum experience you can gain in the game is absolute.  There is no way to gain all the perks as you'll top out at level 81 even if you choose to not level up at all until you max all your skills.

Here is the entire XP curve for Sneak in case you are interested:

[image: chart]

Comment: Cheers. I guess sneak is just one of those skills that's so easy to level, you can do it in one sitting, which gave me the false impression the game had reduced level requirements. I guess it's time to take like thirty levels ups in a row.

Comment: +1 "No Larry, don't vote for the chart!" "I can't help it! It's so beeauutiifuull" *click*

Answer (score 4):

There's no way you could get every perk, since your skills are still going to increase as you use them.  Eventually you'll max all your skills, hit the max number of perks, and still have never entered the level-up screen.

[Gaining Experience in Skyrim](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Leveling)

Answer (score 0):

> can you really get every perk?

As discussed [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34076/whats-the-level-cap-in-skyrim), the level cap is 81.  The max number of perks is 80.

> Is there any advantage in refusing to level up, aside from easier enemies?

Refusing to level does not grant you easier enemies.  This isn't Oblivion.

The only "advantage" for refusing to level is to reserve your 5 skill trains at a trainer for that level.  Once you have bought that training, there is no point in avoiding leveling any longer.

Comment: It does grant you easier enemies. I've never seen an Ancient Dragon at level 1. Once you enter a dungeon, those enemies are permanently set to your level. The only difference versus Oblivion is that dungeons have level ranges (both a floor and a ceiling), so you can wind up quite underpowered for one dungeon and overpowered for another. There's no benefit to refusing to level, unlike Oblivion, but enemies do scale based on your level and would be easier as you gain skill levels.

Comment: There are people at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36180/how-do-i-defeat-a-wispmother-in-skyrim encountering a WispMother while under level 10.

Comment: Level 10 vs Hagraven: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/47254/what-strategy-should-i-use-to-beat-a-hagraven-as-a-sneaky-archer

Comment: Frost troll too hard to kill, more levels is answer: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39011/how-am-i-supposed-to-kill-the-frost-troll

Comment: yeah, levels definitely do affect your enemies. By taking 45 levels in a row it made it really clear... every single dragon I'd faced before then was a generic green dragon. Now every visit to falkrieth comes with an elder dragon, and often a second one at the same time. But generally speaking, refusing to level up was a waste, it's easier to kill that ancient dragon at 45 than it was to kill a plain dragon at 1.